# Functions and value-returning

Tags: python, function, return

So I'm having a hard time grasping return functions just asking if anybody could help solve this and maybe explain returning functions the book I have doesn't go in depth or maybe I just don't understand fully. I want to ask the user for the distance in kilos and then pass it to the other function to calculate how much it is in miles.

```
def kilo(distance):
    distance = int(input('what is the distance'))
    return distance


def miles(trav):
    travel=kilo(trav) * 0.6214
    print(travel)
    return travel
```

Comment: You forgot a closing bracket.

Comment: Those are *not* "return functions", but "return statements".

Comment: And what specifically are you having problems with? Did you ever call `miles`?

Comment: For the record, *all functions* in Python are actual functions, i.e. they have return values. If you don't *explicitly* return a value, your function will *implicitly* return `None`. This is different than other, usually older languages that distinguished between "functions" which returned something, and "subroutines", that did not return anything but produced side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

To use the function, you should call them. You first define them and then later call them with the required arguments.

```
def kilo():
    distance = int(input('what is the distance '))
    return distance

def miles(kms):
    travel = kms * 0.6214
    return travel

kilometers_traveled = kilos()
miles_traveled = miles(kilometers_traveled)

# printing the results:
print("distance in kilometers traveled:", kilometers_traveled)
print("distance in miles traveled:", miles_traveled)

# or shorter:
miles_traveled = miles(kilos())
```

Both functions don't necessarily need to have any arguments, since you ask for the variable in with the `input()` in `kilos`. But there are multiple ways to solve the problem of course, with an argument `kms` you can use the function as converter from kilometers to miles.

Comment: what if i wanted to say  print miles() at the bottom and take out the print travel from inside the function                                                                                         thanks for the response

Comment: Although it's arguably better form to pass the kilometres into `miles` and have it do the conversion based on its parameters instead of necessarily asking the user to type the input in.

Comment: @dc13 see the update, the functions return a value, which you can store into a variable, which you can then later print.

Comment: ok so one more thing could you take distance and pass it as parameter for miles then say travel = distance * 0.6214 and then go from there

Comment: @dc13 That is exactly what is happening. `miles` takes a distance (or as I called it: `kms` (kilometers))

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this if you want to ask the user for input then pass it on to miles

```
def kilo():
    distance = int(input('what is the distance'))
    return distance


def miles():
    travel=kilo() * 0.6214
    print(travel)
    return travel

miles_distance = miles()
```

The kilo function, when called in the miles function will ask the user for the distance then return it. The miles function will then use that distance to calculate and return travel. the value travel is then saved in the miles_distance variable

Answer (score 0):

```
# kilo function to accept distance from user
def kilo():
    distance = int(input('what is the distance'))
    # pass the distance to miles function and save the return value in the variable distance_miles
    distance_miles = miles(distance)
    print(distance_miles)

# miles function to accept distance in kilometers and return distance in miles  
def miles(trav):
    travel = trav * 0.6214
    return travel

# Call the kilo function    
kilo()
```

You can define 2 functions as above.

The code execution flow is

1. The line kilo() calls kilo funtion
2. kilo function accepts distance from user and stores in variable 'distance'
3. kilo calls miles function with parameter 'distance'
4. miles function converts kilo to miles and returns the value in variable 'travel' to kilo function
5. The value returned to the kilo function is saved in the variable 'distance_miles' and printed on the console